# Как сохранить состояния checkbox-ов, после обновления страницы?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webforms, webforms

Есть веб-форма, на которой через хидден филд отображена таблица.
Через функции я провожу проверки некоторые, которые в свою очередь вызывают PopupWindow. Мой вопрос такой. В случае, когда выделен checkbox, и всплывает PopupWindow, отмеченные флажки снимаются, потому что у страницы происходит ре-рендер.

```
lblSortMove.Text = res;
PopupWindow1.ContentPanelId = pnlSortMove.ID;
PopupWindow1.Title = "Тайтл";
pnlSortMove.Visible = true;
cmd.Transaction.Rollback();
return;
```

не понимаю каким образом это реализовать. Из вопросов похожих здесь, видел только на java.

Comment: Сохранять состояние чекбоксов в сессии

Comment: Ре-рендер происходит через контроллер?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц это веб формы, там нет контроллеров

Comment: Вам, скорее всего, придется куда то созранять состояние и потом считывать, например да, как советовали в сессию, или лучше во ViewState (но не уверен, что это сработает)

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц @DmitriyD @tym32167 подскажите пожалуйста, я решил это сделать через viewState. но не понимаю как что здесь не так, поясните кто понимает `string[] VCheckChecked { get { object o = ViewState["_VCheckChecked"]; if (o == null)return ""; return (string[])ViewState["_VCheckChecked"]; } set { ViewState["_VCheckChecked"] = value; } }`